# Detecting if a MTLTexture is blank

Tags: ios, swift, metal

I am trying to determine if a MTLTexture (in bgra8Unorm format) is blank by calculating the sum of all the R G B and A components of each of its pixels.

This function intends to do this by adding adjacent floats in memory after a texture has been copied to a pointer. However I have determined that this function ends up returning false nomatter the MTLTexture given.

What is wrong with this function?

```
func anythingHere(_ texture: MTLTexture) -> Bool {
        let width = texture.width
        let height = texture.height
        let bytesPerRow = width * 4

        let data = UnsafeMutableRawPointer.allocate(bytes: bytesPerRow * height, alignedTo: 4)
        defer {
            data.deallocate(bytes: bytesPerRow * height, alignedTo: 4)
        }

        let region = MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, width, height)
        texture.getBytes(data, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, from: region, mipmapLevel: 0)
        var bind = data.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)

        var sum:UInt8 = 0;
        for i in 0..<width*height {
            sum += bind.pointee
            bind.advanced(by: 1)
        }
        return sum != 0
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matthijs' change is necessary, but there are also a couple of other issues with the correctness of this method.

You're actually only iterating over 1/4 of the pixels, since you're stepping byte-wise and the upper bound of your loop is `width * height` rather than `bytesPerRow * height`.

Additionally, computing the sum of the pixels doesn't really seem like what you want. You can save some work by returning true as soon as you encounter a non-zero value (`if bind.pointee != 0`).

(Incidentally, Swift's integer overflow protection will actually raise an exception if you accumulate a value greater than 255 into a `UInt8`. I suppose you could use a bigger integer, or disable overflow checking with `sum = sum &+ bind.pointee`, but again, breaking the loop on the first non-clear pixel will save some time and prevent false positives when the accumulator "rolls over" to exactly 0.)

Here's a version of your function that worked for me:

```
func anythingHere(_ texture: MTLTexture) -> Bool {
    let width = texture.width
    let height = texture.height
    let bytesPerRow = width * 4

    let data = UnsafeMutableRawPointer.allocate(byteCount: bytesPerRow * height, alignment: 4)
    defer {
        data.deallocate()
    }

    let region = MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, width, height)
    texture.getBytes(data, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, from: region, mipmapLevel: 0)
    var bind = data.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)

    for _ in 0..<bytesPerRow * height {
        if bind.pointee != 0 {
            return true
        }
        bind = bind.advanced(by: 1)
    }
    return false
}
```

Keep in mind that on macOS, the default `storageMode` for textures is `managed`, which means their contents aren't automatically synchronized back to main memory when they're modified on the GPU. You must explicitly use a blit command encoder to sync the contents yourself:

```
let syncEncoder = buffer.makeBlitCommandEncoder()!
syncEncoder.synchronize(resource: texture)
syncEncoder.endEncoding()
```

Comment: Minor edits to that code have to be made to make it run in XCode 9.2 Swift 4. When I make those edits it does not work unfortunately. Have you tried it on the latest version of XCode for a MacOS App?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to mention I was using Swift 4.1 and  Xcode 9.3 beta 3. Very unusual that it’s not working after those changes for you. Can you post the calling code and describe how you’re creating the texture?

Comment: More specifically, have you tried setting a breakpoint and stepping through the loop to see what happens when a known-good texture (eg, one whose upper-left pixel is white) is passed in?

Comment: Yah so most notably on the default OSX Metal project I run the function for the texture used on the cube in the init method of the Renderer right before the super.init() line.

Comment: I put the project file I am working on in a zip here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rNDDIn59rmY6MGVOuhbswqn-4paSaGy1 . The other texture I am trying to read is a one turned teal by a compute shader (you can check this by debugging the frame). If any of the reports was true it would be great news. Everything is in edits.swift

Comment: You're using a managed storage mode and not synchronizing the texture contents after modifying it on the GPU, which is required when reading the contents on the CPU. I've added a snippet above that does this.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't look in detail at the rest of the code, but I think this,

```
bind.advanced(by: 1)
```

should be:

```
bind = bind.advanced(by: 1)
```

Comment: Good catch! Unfortunately still does not work even with that edit.